# Hidden admin account?

Tags: windows-7, administrator

I have a non-domain connected pc on which I have a local admin account (user is part of the admin group). However there are certain things I cannot do. For example there is a folder containing some software I cannot delete or some Chrome plugins that I cannot delete. In case of the Chrome plugin I also couldn't find the corresponding group policy as explained in Google's documentation.

This pc is provided by work so I assume there is some super admin account or something that is hiding/preventing things from me. As I am local admin, and this is not a domain connected pc, how are they doing this? Out of interest I want to know and try and get around it.

Comment: You could lose your job doing that. We will not help with company owned PC's here at SU

Comment: "For example, there is a folder containing some software I cannot delete" - What folder and who actually owns the folder?  Edit your question, please do not submit a comment, providing this vital required information.  "Super Administrators" do not exist on Windows.

Comment: @Moab IT is fine with it, they want to know if somebody can work around it.

Comment: @Ramhound Administrators is the owner, my user is a member of that group.

Comment: There are operating-system level "accounts" in Windows that have access to things that administrators do not. For example, "TrustedInstaller", "System", "NetworkService", etc. Messing around with such things frequently leads to unhappy results.